# Conditional image path using Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two images progress.png and completed.png. Depending on the status in the db table (In Progress of Complete), I want to display the appropriate image. What is the correct syntax for the IIF() statement within asp.net? Thanks for your help.

```
pseudocode:

<asp:image ImageUrl='<%# IIF(Eval("Status").Equals("In Progress")
display - 'images/progress.png') 
else if status equals "Complete"
display - 'images/complete.png' %>' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this will not answer your question regarding the IIF syntax, but will solve your problem regarding displaying the image.

I would rather use this:

```
<asp:image ImageUrl='<%# GetStatusImage(Eval("Status").ToString()) %>' />
```

and write the following method in your code-behind.

```
public string GetStatusImage(string status)
{
     switch(status)
         case "In Progress":
             return "images/progress.png";
         break;
         case "Complete":
             return "images/complete.png";
         break;
         case default:
             return string.Empty;
         break;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is create a public method that would return the right image and the call the method from code like this:

```
<%= GetProgressImage() %>
```

Alternatively, this might work if you have only two states:

```
<%= Eval("Status").Equals("Complete") ? "'images/complete.png'"  : "'images/progress.png'"   %>
```